# ConnectTimeoutException: connent to /Ipaddress:80 time out

Tags: android, web-services, rest

I encountered exception **org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to /Ipaddress of my computer:80 timed out** when i run my android apps on real device(device is micromax canvas2 and version- 4.2.1). due to this user can not able to login but when i run this apps on emulator it's run successfully but not running on real device. I goggled lot and tried some solution but does not achieve my goal and i am trying still. please anybody help me to solve the problem. 
Following is the my code structure.

In **LoginActivity** I call the method for making the http request

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", login_tag));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", username));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", userpsw));
        JsonParserWebs jsonDataFromSrvr = new JsonParserWebs();
        String loginData = jsonDataFromSrvr.makeHttpReqToSrvr(loginUrl,"POST", params);
```

Following is the **JsonParserWebs** for calling webservice

```
public String makeHttpReqToSrvr(String url,String requestType,List<NameValuePair> params) {
    Log.i(JsonParserWebs.class.getName(),"URL..."+url);
    HttpEntity httpEntity=null;

    //making http request
    try {

        if (requestType == "GET") {

            //connection time out
            HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 5000);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 10000);

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
            String paramString =URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url+"?"+paramString);



            HttpResponse httpResp = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            httpEntity = httpResp.getEntity();

        }
        if (requestType == "POST") {

            //connection time out
            // From stackoverflow, I addes following three line but still got ConnectTimeoutException
            HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 5000);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 10000);

            HttpClient  httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResp = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            httpEntity = httpResp.getEntity();

        }

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {

        json = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
        Log.v("JSON", "data"+json);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    // try parse the string to a JSON object

    return json;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: is your URL working? try it on browser

Comment: are you using localhost in your URL?

Comment: yes i am using localhost wamp server.

Comment: no.. is your URL is like this : localhost:80?

Comment: no i am using url like "/Ipaddress of my computer/index.php"

Comment: your device and your URL uses same network?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39985/discussion-between-nilesh-wani-and-droid)

Comment: @nileshwani can you get any solution for this?